# Array of properties of objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Given the array of objects:

```
data = [{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, {a: 4, b: 5, c: 6}, {a: 7, b: 8, c: 9}]
```

How can I get an array of only `a` elements of the objects? Something like this:

```
a = [1, 4, 7]
```

Is it possible without iterating through the objects?

Comment: Why are you trying to do it without iterating through the objects?

Comment: Hint: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: no, but you can use a `forEach` call instead of an explicit loop

Comment: @ChristopherMesser I just wondered if ther'es an implementation for this, like the given array.map() method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is easy to achieve with [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var data = [{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, {a: 4, b: 5, c: 6}, {a: 7, b: 8, c: 9}];
var a = data.map(obj => obj.a);
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also try this:

```
var result = data.reduce(function(result, obj) {
        return result.concat(obj.a);
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several methods.
You should look into `Array.map()` or the powerful Lodash library.

```
let aElements = data.map(o => o.a);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using functional programming(map higher-order function):

```
var a = data.map(function(obj){return obj.a});
```

or the same in es6:

```
let a = data.map(obj=>obj.a);
```

But, nevertheless, technically `Array.prototype.map` iterates.